# postfix tcp_table lookup format

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm trying to learn / understand more about postfix tcp_table lookup interface and I'm having a difficult time understanding exactly what the reply format should be.

There is clear documentation that the request/  return format is

```
XXX SPACE *text* NEWLINE
```

but it's really unclear to me what the *text* is or could be.  Could someone point me to something more with a little more detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following `python` script(simple tcp server)just returns `REJECT User is blacklisted` for any data it receive.

```
import SocketServer

class MyTCPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
  def handle(self):
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print "{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0])
    print self.data
    # reply data
    data = '200 REJECT%20User%20is%20blacklisted\n'
    self.request.send(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999
  server = SocketServer.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)
  server.serve_forever()
```

After starting the server, You can query this as

```
[clement@myhost ~]$ postmap -q user@domain.com tcp:localhost:9999
REJECT User is blacklisted
```

So the `text` is the string that returns some human readable description.It is the same `text` you sepcify in your [access](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) table. Eg.`user@domain.tld REJECT You are blacklisted`